# Wrong numbers when calculating broadcast address

Tags: c++, c, mask, broadcast, subnet

I'm having troubles calculating the broadcast address using IP address and subnet mask. It seems easy, it should be just broadcast=ip|~mask , but it doesn't seeem to be working in my case. I've tried using + instead of OR operator and using unsigned int instead of signed, but it still doesn't work. Here is the part of the code that does this operation, I hope you can help me. Arrays net[] which is an IP adress and mask[] are integers, previously used in program, and are outputed correctly and work fine in other operations inside my program (turning them into binary, calculating the network address by using & between them etc.)

```
int broadcast[4];    
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++) 
     broadcast[i]=net[i]|(~mask[i]);
```

For 192.168.50.50 and 255.255.0.0 as net[] and mask[] I expect broadcast to be **192.168.255.255**, but I get **-64.-88.-1.-1**

Comment: What are the values of `mask` and `net`? I suspect your `~mask[i]` flips more than the eight bits of each octet in the IP address, so you end up with negative numbers because you flip the top bit in the `int`...

Comment: Note that `(unsigned char)(-1) == 255`, `(unsigned char)(-88) == 168`, etc

Comment: @hlt: Doesn't matter what the values are, operand promotions guarantee that the result of `~` has more than 8 bits.

Comment: You are absolutely right, of course @BenVoigt

Answer (score 5):

The output you're seeing is because you're using signed values and printing the results as signed values.

Change the types of the values to `unsigned char` and print with `%hhu`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use unsigned char as the type. Each part of the IP is a non-negative number between 0-255.